# SwiperJS : slide order and slide per column does not work properly in grid

Tags: javascript, vue.js, swiper.js

sandbox: [demo](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/swiper-grid-forked-5tm9nl?file=%2Findex.html)

Swiper version: ^11.0.5

The order of the slide displayed and the rows per column is not as expected. I am working on Vue using the swiper element but the same problem is shown in the simple html demo. In order to get 3 rows per column in 1 view, I have set

1. slidesPerView: 1
2. grid: {
   rows: 3,
   fill: "row"
   }

However, only 2 rows are shown in the 1st page and the order is not in ascending order.

I am looping through the slides so it is not possible to put 3 elements in 1 slide.

I have tried to remove property fill but then all slides are shown in the 1st page. Editing CSS of .swiper-wrapper to display:grid; grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr); also does not work. It causes the same result. SlidesPerColumn does not work in this swiper version.

Is there any solution on this issue?

**Expected behavior**

for 1st page

1

2

3

for 2nd page

4

**Actual behavior**

for 1st page

1

3

for 2nd page

2

4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the grid option `fill: "row"` to `fill: "column"`

[updated codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/swiper-grid-forked-hs3rn2?file=%2Findex.html%3A67%2C27)

Be careful with the CSS.  Your codesandbox has it commented out currently, but this CSS will cause all 4 slides to appear on the same page:

```css
swiper-slide {
  height: calc((100% - 30px) / 4) !important;
}
```

So that's probably why you had that problem earlier.  The `4` value needs to match the number of rows. Swiperjs will calculate the correct value on its own while this CSS remains commented out, but if you reenable this CSS just make sure to update the height calculation to `(100% - 30px) / 3`.

Answer (score 0):

In my real project, I solve it in this way.

1. set the height in the swiper container (e.g 70vh) and
2. set the fill to column

If you swipe through the slides but it is swiped only half way through the slide, please set .swiper-wrapper { width: 0 !important; }, then the issue should be solved.